# CSOM - Get ViewCount for modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, csom

I am trying to get the "ViewCount" for a modern page via CSOM. I get the property 
`ViewsLifeTime`
via CSOM Search API:

```
[...]
var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(sourceSiteCtx);
keywordQuery.QueryText = @"Path: " + itemUrl;
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(sourceSiteCtx);
var resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
sourceSiteCtx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
foreach (var result in resultTableCollection.Value[0].ResultRows)
{
    var viewsLifeTime = result["ViewsLifeTime"];
}
[...}
```

But the value there is another then on the page (ViewsLifeTime is 463 in my case). When I look in the Developer Tools on the page, it makes a request to 
`https://***-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/document/metadata?siteId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx` and returns the "right" value

```
SavedForLater: false
Type: "ItemMetadata"
ViewCount: 261
```

Is there any chance to get "ViewCount" via CSOM?